# Bash merge columned files into one file with rows

Tags: excel, bash

I have many data files in this format:

```
-1597.5421
-1909.6982
-1991.8743
-2033.5744
```

But I would like to merge them all into one data file with each original data file taking up one row with spaces in between so I can import it in excel.

```
-1597.5421 -1909.6982 -1991.8743 -2033.5744
-1789.3324 -1234.5678 -9876.5433 -9999.4321
```

And so on. Each file is named `ALL.ene` and every directory in my working directory contains it. Can someone give me a quick fix? Thanks!

:edit. Each file has 11 entries. Those were just examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i in */ALL.ene
do
echo $(<$i)
done > result.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

**Assumptions:**

I assume all your data files are of this format:

```
<something1><newline>
<something2><newline>
<something3><newline>
```

So for example, if the last newline is missing, the following script will miss the field corresponding to `<something3>`.

**Usage:** `./merge.bash -o <output file> <input file list or glob>`

The script appends to any existing output files from previous runs. It also does not make any assumptions to how many fields of data every input file has. It blindly puts every line into a line in the output file separated by spaces.

```
#!/bin/bash

# set -o xtrace # uncomment to debug

declare output

[[ $1 =~ -o$ ]] && output="$2" && shift 2 || { \
    echo "The first argument should always be -o <output>";
    exit -1; } 

declare -a files=("${@}") row

for file in "${files[@]}";
do
    while read data; do
    row+=("$data")
    done < "$file"
    echo "${row[@]}" >> "$output"
    row=()
done
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat data1
-1597.5421
-1909.6982
-1991.8743
-2033.5744
$ cat data2
-1789.3324
-1234.5678
-9876.5433
-9999.4321
$ ./merge.bash -o test data{1,2}
$ cat test
-1597.5421 -1909.6982 -1991.8743 -2033.5744
-1789.3324 -1234.5678 -9876.5433 -9999.4321
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what `coreutils` `paste` is good at, try:

```
paste -s data_files*
```